# Callback of tweet triggers before tweet?

Tags: javascript, twitter, callback, tweets

I want to have a callback function for twitter tweet button.

I have gone through the doc and implemented code accordingly but that callback triggers as soon as tweet popup opens but I need that calllback once tweet is done.

Following is my code

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://google.com" data-size="large">Tweet</a>



//Twitter Widgets JS
                window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
                 var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
                js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
                }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

                //Once twttr is ready, bind a callback function to the tweet event
                twttr.ready(function(twttr) {       
                    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
                        alert('tweet, tweet');

                    });
                });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24bdr048/1/)

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?